# How can I view the source code for a function?

Tags: r, function, debugging, r-faq

I want to look at the source code for a function to see how it works. I know I can print a function by typing its name at the prompt:

```
> t
function (x) 
UseMethod("t")
<bytecode: 0x2332948>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

In this case, what does `UseMethod("t")` mean?  How do I find the source code that's actually being used by, for example: `t(1:10)`?

Is there a difference between when I see `UseMethod` and when I see `standardGeneric` and `showMethods`, as with `with`?

```
> with
standardGeneric for "with" defined from package "base"

function (data, expr, ...) 
standardGeneric("with")
<bytecode: 0x102fb3fc0>
<environment: 0x102fab988>
Methods may be defined for arguments: data
Use  showMethods("with")  for currently available ones.
```

In other cases, I can see that R functions are being called, but I can't find the source code for those functions.

```
> ts.union
function (..., dframe = FALSE) 
.cbind.ts(list(...), .makeNamesTs(...), dframe = dframe, union = TRUE)
<bytecode: 0x36fbf88>
<environment: namespace:stats>
> .cbindts
Error: object '.cbindts' not found
> .makeNamesTs
Error: object '.makeNamesTs' not found
```

How do I find functions like `.cbindts` and `.makeNamesTs`?

In still other cases, there's a bit of R code, but most of work seems to be done somewhere else.

```
> matrix
function (data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL) 
{
    if (is.object(data) || !is.atomic(data)) 
        data <- as.vector(data)
    .Internal(matrix(data, nrow, ncol, byrow, dimnames, missing(nrow), 
        missing(ncol)))
}
<bytecode: 0x134bd10>
<environment: namespace:base>
> .Internal
function (call)  .Primitive(".Internal")
> .Primitive
function (name)  .Primitive(".Primitive")
```

How do I find out what the `.Primitive` function does?  Similarly, some functions call `.C`, `.Call`, `.Fortran`, `.External`, or `.Internal`.  How can I find the source code for those?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1439348/134830

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function/14035586

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385411/where-is-the-r-script-file-located-on-the-pc

Answer (score 644, accepted):

`UseMethod("t")` is telling you that `t()` is a ([S3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6583639/1412059)) generic function that has methods for different object classes.

## The S3 method dispatch system

For S3 classes, you can use the `methods` function to list the methods for a particular generic function or class.

```
> methods(t)
[1] t.data.frame t.default    t.ts*       

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
> methods(class="ts")
 [1] aggregate.ts     as.data.frame.ts cbind.ts*        cycle.ts*       
 [5] diffinv.ts*      diff.ts          kernapply.ts*    lines.ts        
 [9] monthplot.ts*    na.omit.ts*      Ops.ts*          plot.ts         
[13] print.ts         time.ts*         [<-.ts*          [.ts*           
[17] t.ts*            window<-.ts*     window.ts*      

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

"Non-visible functions are asterisked" means the function is not exported from its package's namespace.  You can still view its source code via the `:::` function (i.e. `stats:::t.ts`), or by using `getAnywhere()`.  `getAnywhere()` is useful because you don't have to know which package the function came from.

```
> getAnywhere(t.ts)
A single object matching ‘t.ts’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for t from namespace stats
  namespace:stats
with value

function (x) 
{
    cl <- oldClass(x)
    other <- !(cl %in% c("ts", "mts"))
    class(x) <- if (any(other)) 
        cl[other]
    attr(x, "tsp") <- NULL
    t(x)
}
<bytecode: 0x294e410>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

## The S4 method dispatch system

The S4 system is a newer method dispatch system and is an alternative to the S3 system. Here is an example of an S4 function:

```
> library(Matrix)
Loading required package: lattice
> chol2inv
standardGeneric for "chol2inv" defined from package "base"

function (x, ...) 
standardGeneric("chol2inv")
<bytecode: 0x000000000eafd790>
<environment: 0x000000000eb06f10>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods("chol2inv")  for currently available ones.
```

The output already offers a lot of information. `standardGeneric` is an indicator of an S4 function. The method to see defined S4 methods is offered helpfully:

```
> showMethods(chol2inv)
Function: chol2inv (package base)
x="ANY"
x="CHMfactor"
x="denseMatrix"
x="diagonalMatrix"
x="dtrMatrix"
x="sparseMatrix"
```

`getMethod` can be used to see the source code of one of the methods:

```
> getMethod("chol2inv", "diagonalMatrix")
Method Definition:

function (x, ...) 
{
    chk.s(...)
    tcrossprod(solve(x))
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000ea2cc70>
<environment: namespace:Matrix>

Signatures:
        x               
target  "diagonalMatrix"
defined "diagonalMatrix"
```

There are also methods with more complex signatures for each method, for example

```
require(raster)
showMethods(extract)
Function: extract (package raster)
x="Raster", y="data.frame"
x="Raster", y="Extent"
x="Raster", y="matrix"
x="Raster", y="SpatialLines"
x="Raster", y="SpatialPoints"
x="Raster", y="SpatialPolygons"
x="Raster", y="vector"
```

To see the source code for one of these methods the entire signature must be supplied, e.g.

```
getMethod("extract" , signature = c( x = "Raster" , y = "SpatialPolygons") )
```

It will not suffice to supply the partial signature

```
getMethod("extract",signature="SpatialPolygons")
#Error in getMethod("extract", signature = "SpatialPolygons") : 
#  No method found for function "extract" and signature SpatialPolygons
```

## Functions that call unexported functions

In the case of `ts.union`, `.cbindts` and `.makeNamesTs` are unexported functions from the `stats` namespace. You can view the source code of unexported functions by using the `:::` operator or `getAnywhere`.

```
> stats:::.makeNamesTs
function (...) 
{
    l <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
    nm <- names(l)
    fixup <- if (is.null(nm)) 
        seq_along(l)
    else nm == ""
    dep <- sapply(l[fixup], function(x) deparse(x)[1L])
    if (is.null(nm)) 
        return(dep)
    if (any(fixup)) 
        nm[fixup] <- dep
    nm
}
<bytecode: 0x38140d0>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

## Functions that call compiled code

Note that "compiled" does not refer to byte-compiled R code as created by the **compiler** package. The `<bytecode: 0x294e410>` line in the above output indicates that the function is byte-compiled, and you can still view the source from the R command line.

Functions that call `.C`, `.Call`, `.Fortran`, `.External`, `.Internal`, or `.Primitive` are calling entry points in compiled code, so you will have to look at sources of the compiled code if you want to fully understand the function. [This](https://github.com/wch/r-source) GitHub mirror of the R source code is a decent place to start. The function `pryr::show_c_source` can be a useful tool as it will take you directly to a GitHub page for `.Internal` and `.Primitive` calls. Packages may use `.C`, `.Call`, `.Fortran`, and `.External`; but not `.Internal` or `.Primitive`, because these are used to call functions built into the R interpreter.

Calls to some of the above functions may use an object instead of a character string to reference the compiled function. In those cases, the object is of class `"NativeSymbolInfo"`, `"RegisteredNativeSymbol"`, or `"NativeSymbol"`; and printing the object yields useful information.  For example, `optim` calls `.External2(C_optimhess, res$par, fn1, gr1, con)` (note that's `C_optimhess`, not `"C_optimhess"`).  `optim` is in the stats package, so you can type `stats:::C_optimhess` to see information about the compiled function being called.

### Compiled code in a package

If you want to view compiled code in a package, you will need to download/unpack the package source. The installed binaries are not sufficient. A package's source code is available from the same CRAN (or CRAN compatible) repository that the package was originally installed from. The `download.packages()` function can get the package source for you.

```
download.packages(pkgs = "Matrix", 
                  destdir = ".",
                  type = "source")
```

This will download the source version of the Matrix package and save the corresponding `.tar.gz` file in the current directory. Source code for compiled functions can be found in the `src` directory of the uncompressed and untared file. The uncompressing and untaring step can be done outside of `R`, or from within `R` using the `untar()` function. It is possible to combine the download and expansion step into a single call (note that only one package at a time can be downloaded and unpacked in this way):

```
untar(download.packages(pkgs = "Matrix",
                        destdir = ".",
                        type = "source")[,2])
```

Alternatively, if the package development is hosted publicly (e.g. via [GitHub](http://www.github.com), [R-Forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org), or [RForge.net](http://www.rforge.net)), you can probably browse the source code online.

### Compiled code in a base package

Certain packages are considered "base" packages. These packages ship with R and their version is locked to the version of R. Examples include `base`, `compiler`, `stats`, and `utils`. As such, they are not available as separate downloadable packages on CRAN as described above. Rather, they are part of the R source tree in individual package directories under `/src/library/`. How to access the R source is described in the next section.

### Compiled code built into the R interpreter

If you want to view the code built-in to the R interpreter, you will need to download/unpack the R sources; or you can view the sources online via the R [Subversion repository](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/) or [Winston Chang's github mirror](https://github.com/wch/r-source/tree/trunk).

Uwe Ligges's [R news article (PDF)](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf) (p. 43) is a good general reference of how to view the source code for `.Internal` and `.Primitive` functions.  The basic steps are to first look for the function name in `src/main/names.c` and then search for the "C-entry" name in the files in `src/main/*`.

Comment: If you use `RStudio`, it will attempt to pull the source for the function your text cursor is over if you press the `F2` key.

Comment: @Ari B. Friedman Sorry for this late question. Will RStudio also pull the C source code for the function or just for the functions written in R? Thanks

Comment: @Samir I believe it's just the R source.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman - thanks Ari, this is handy. In my case I still needed the knowledge shown in the answer (`scale`, which is S3 - I got `UseMethod("scale")` and then used `getAnywhere(scale.default)`). But plain functions work just fine.

Comment: Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery I assume this answer / wiki came first :) Before this http://rfaqs.com/source-code-of-r-method

Comment: How can we find the compiled code in [this](https://github.com/wch/r-source/tree/trunk/src/library/stats/src) github folder? I want to find the source code for function `stl` and it calls a Fortran function `z <- .Fortran(C_stl, x, n, as.integer(period)...`. But I can't find `C_stl` in that folder. Would it be somewhere else?

Comment: @yuqli: Note that it's `C_stl`, not `"C_stl"`. Use `print(stats:::C_stl)` to see the `NativeSymbolInfo` for the `C_stl` object. That shows that the Fortran function name is "stl", which is in the `stl.f` file.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks for the response! I later searched "stl" and did also find the `stl.f` file. But thanks so much for teaching me the trick of printing and the difference between an object and a file.

Comment: Alas `getMethod()` is deprecated and not longer available. The help file for `findMethods()` which replaced it does not show how to get the source code for S4 methods.

Comment: I'm using R version `4.1.3` and `getMethod()` works just fine for me i.e. gives the same output as in this post.

Answer (score 114):

In addition to the other answers on this question and its duplicates, here's a good way to get source code for a package function without needing to know which package it's in.
e.g. say if we want the source for `randomForest::rfcv()`:

#### To **view/edit** it in a pop-up window:

```
edit(getAnywhere('rfcv'), file='source_rfcv.r')

View(getAnywhere('rfcv'), file='source_rfcv.r')
```

Note that `edit()` opens a text editor (of user's choice), whereas
`View()` invokes a spreadsheet-style data viewer.

- `View()` is great for browsing (multi-columnar) **data**, but usually terrible for **code** of anything other than toy length.
- so when only want to **view code**, `edit()` is IMO actually far better than `View()`, since with `edit()` you can collapse/hide/dummy out all the arg-parsing/checking/default/error-message logic which can take up to 70% of an R function, and just get to the part where the function actually operationally does something(!), what type(s) of objects its return type is, whether and how it recurses, etc.

#### To **redirect to a separate file** (so you can bring up the code in your favorite IDE/editor/process it with grep/etc.):

```
capture.output(getAnywhere('rfcv'), file='source_rfcv.r')
```

Comment: Admittedly, *getAnywhere* is another wacky R choice of name for something which should have been called *findOnSearchPath* or similar.

Comment: I'll upvote this answer because it got me close to what I wanted. What I actually wanted, in RStudio, was `View(foo)`; where `foo` was a function from an already loaded package.

Comment: @Sigfried: [`edit()` opens a text editor (of user's choice)](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/edit.html), whereas [`View()` opens an Excel-type spreadsheet viewer for *data*](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/View.html), the latter is good for browsing (multi-columnar) data, but usually terrible for code of anything other than toy length. For example as I hint at, generally the first thing I want to do when browsing a function is skip/collapse/dummy out all the arg-parsing and default-action logic, to see what the function actually *does*.

Comment: @Sigfried: updated to incorporate all those remarks/tips.

Answer (score 35):

For non-primitive functions, R base includes a function called `body()` that returns the body of function.  For instance the source of the `print.Date()` function can be viewed:

```
body(print.Date)
```

will produce this:

```
{
    if (is.null(max)) 
        max <- getOption("max.print", 9999L)
    if (max < length(x)) {
        print(format(x[seq_len(max)]), max = max, ...)
        cat(" [ reached getOption(\"max.print\") -- omitted", 
            length(x) - max, "entries ]\n")
    }
    else print(format(x), max = max, ...)
    invisible(x)
}
```

If you are working in a script and want the function code as a character vector, you can get it.

```
capture.output(print(body(print.Date)))
```

will get you:

```
[1] "{"                                                                   
[2] "    if (is.null(max)) "                                              
[3] "        max <- getOption(\"max.print\", 9999L)"                      
[4] "    if (max < length(x)) {"                                          
[5] "        print(format(x[seq_len(max)]), max = max, ...)"              
[6] "        cat(\" [ reached getOption(\\\"max.print\\\") -- omitted\", "
[7] "            length(x) - max, \"entries ]\\n\")"                      
[8] "    }"                                                               
[9] "    else print(format(x), max = max, ...)"                           
[10] "    invisible(x)"                                                    
[11] "}"
```

Why would I want to do such a thing?  I was creating a custom S3 object (`x`, where `class(x) = "foo"`) based on a list.  One of the list members (named "fun") was a function and I wanted `print.foo()` to display the function source code, indented.  So I ended up with the following snippet in `print.foo()`:

```
sourceVector = capture.output(print(body(x[["fun"]])))
cat(paste0("      ", sourceVector, "\n"))
```

which indents and displays the code associated with `x[["fun"]]`.

*Edit 2020-12-31*

A less circuitous way to get the same `character` vector of source code is:

```
sourceVector = deparse(body(x$fun))
```

Answer (score 31):

It gets revealed when you debug using the debug() function. 
Suppose you want to see the underlying code in t() transpose function. Just typing 't', doesn't reveal much.

```
>t 
function (x) 
UseMethod("t")
<bytecode: 0x000000003085c010>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

But, Using the 'debug(functionName)', it reveals the underlying code, sans the internals.

```
> debug(t)
> t(co2)
debugging in: t(co2)
debug: UseMethod("t")
Browse[2]> 
debugging in: t.ts(co2)
debug: {
    cl <- oldClass(x)
    other <- !(cl %in% c("ts", "mts"))
    class(x) <- if (any(other)) 
        cl[other]
    attr(x, "tsp") <- NULL
    t(x)
}
Browse[3]> 
debug: cl <- oldClass(x)
Browse[3]> 
debug: other <- !(cl %in% c("ts", "mts"))
Browse[3]> 
debug: class(x) <- if (any(other)) cl[other]
Browse[3]>  
debug: attr(x, "tsp") <- NULL
Browse[3]> 
debug: t(x)
```

**EDIT:**
debugonce() accomplishes the same without having to use undebug()

Comment: The downsides of this method compared to the ones given in the accepted answer are that you need a working function call (all necessary parameters specified, acceptably); and that, in addition to the initial block of code, you also get each block at the time it is run. This is great for debugging, but not optimal for just getting the source.

Comment: Yes, its not optimal. But if you are clever, you can get the source quick and dirty, esp for in-built functions.

Comment: I'd also recommend using `debugonce` instead of `debug` in this instance.

Answer (score 22):

Didn't see how this fit into the flow of the main answer but it stumped me for a while so I'm adding it here:

## Infix Operators

To see the source code of some base infix operators (e.g., `%%`, `%*%`, `%in%`), use `getAnywhere`, e.g.:

```
getAnywhere("%%")
# A single object matching ‘%%’ was found
# It was found in the following places
#   package:base
#   namespace:base
#  with value
#
# function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("%%")
```

The main answer covers how to then use mirrors to dig deeper.

Comment: [smci's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23818290/271616) recommended `getAnywhere`. Or you could just use backticks if you already know the name of the operator: `\`%in%\``.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich didn't know you could use backticks! Thanks. `getAnywhere` is mentioned in your answer as well, but I think a specific reference to infix is useful for future reference to this answer -- I've read this page many a time and was still a bit perplexed trying to find code for such functions for a while -- and I didn't think it fit into the flow of either other answer (which are both using `getAnywhere` for another purpose).

Answer (score 15):

In RStudio, there are (at least) 3 ways:

1. Press the F2 key while cursor is on any function.
2. Click on the function name while holding
   Ctrl or Command
3. `View`(function_name) (as stated above)

A new pane will open with the source code. If you reach .Primitive or .C you'll need another method, sorry.

Answer (score 14):

There is a very handy function in R `edit`

```
new_optim <- edit(optim)
```

It will open the source code of `optim` using the editor specified in R's `options`, and then you can edit it and assign the modified function to `new_optim`. I like this function very much to view code or to debug the code, e.g, print some messages or variables or even assign them to a global variables for further investigation (of course you can use `debug`).

If you just want to view the source code and don't want the annoying long source code printed on your console, you can use

```
invisible(edit(optim))
```

Clearly, this cannot be used to view C/C++ or Fortran source code.

BTW, `edit` can open other objects like list, matrix, etc, which then shows the data structure with attributes as well.  Function `de` can be used to open an excel like editor (if GUI supports it) to modify matrix or data frame and return the new one. This is handy sometimes, but should be avoided in usual case, especially when you matrix is big.

Comment: This approach only brings up the same function source that printing the function gives (that is, the same as in the question). Getting further/deeper than that is what this question is about.

Comment: @BrianDiggs Yes, you are right. I did not mean to give an answer to the question, since Joshua has given a quite complete answer. I just try to add something related to the topic,  interesting and may be useful to know about.

Comment: Excuse me, I had posted this 7 months earlier. The use of `invisible(edit(...))` is a good tip though, also the remark "doesn't work on C/C++ or Fortran".

Answer (score 9):

As long as the function is written in pure R not C/C++/Fortran, one may use the following. Otherwise the best way is **debugging** and using "**jump** **into**":

```
> functionBody(functionName)
```

Comment: This is the same as `body`. `identical(functionBody, body)` is `TRUE`.

Comment: `base::body` and `methods::functionBody`, though they're unlikey to be detahed. `body` could be overridden too: https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=body

Answer (score 6):

`View(function_name)` - eg. `View(mean)` Make sure to use uppercase [V]. The read-only code will open in the editor.

Comment: ?View requires a data frame like object, it does not accept a function (in base R). What you are describing is an RStudio modification.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try to use `print.function()`, which is S3 generic, to get the function write in the console.

Comment: `print.function()` is a S3 *method*.  The generic is `print()`.  And it's generally not a good idea to call methods directly.  That defeats the entire purpose of generic functions and method dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

To see the source code of the function use print()

```
f <- function(x){
     x * 2
 }

print(f)

function(x){
    x * 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### First, try running the function without `()`

Example: let's get the source code for the `cat()` function:

```
cat
    if (is.character(file)) 
        if (file == "") 
            file <- stdout()
        else if (startsWith(file, "|")) {
            file <- pipe(substring(file, 2L), "w")
            on.exit(close(file))
        }
        else {
            file <- file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))
            on.exit(close(file))
        }
    .Internal(cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append))
```

#### But sometimes that will return "UseMethod" instead of source code

If we try to get the source code for `read_xml()`:

```
library(xml2)
read_xml 
# UseMethod("read_xml")
```

That's not much use to us! In this case, take a look at the methods:

```
methods("read_xml")
# read_xml.character* read_xml.connection* read_xml.raw* read_xml.response*
```

And use getAnywhere on the value(s) above to see the source code:

```
getAnywhere("read_xml.character")
```

#### Another example

Let's try to see the source code for `qqnorm()`:

```
qqnorm
# UseMethod("qqnorm") # Not very useful

methods("qqnorm")
# [1] qqnorm.default* # Making progress...

getAnywhere("qqnorm.default") # Shows source code!
```

Comment: Did you read the answer by @JoshuaUlrich?

Comment: @JosephWood I did, it was where I got these techniques from a few years ago. I was recently asked why the source code for `qqnorm()` doesn't appear when someone runs `qqnorm` so referred to this question/answers, but couldn't figure it out rapidly, so decided to leave my own answer giving a small handful of MRE's (albeit limited ones, not demonstrating more complicated situations, for example invoking c/c++/fortran code etc). If I've missed something, or if I'm wrong please point out and I'll amend.

Comment: It has been my experience that posting an answer that doesn't add any new information is generally not received well. Especially noting that there is no disclaimer that this is essentially a condensed version of the accepted canonical answer.

Comment: @JosephWood Your points are fair. I'd hold that simple answers are sometimes nice (even nic*er*).. Mine's a 30 seconds read for a newbie, the top answer is much more thorough and hence takes more time, which can be intimidating for someone after a quick, practical answer. Mine is not comprehensive, nor does it try to explain *why* functions can require different methods to discover their source, instead, it gives examples for how to get the source code for a function, without needing to know too much about R's dispatch system, so it's reductionist and simpler, albeit nowhere near as thorough.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution for the R-plugin in PyCharm (for  RStudio, see the answer by @Arthur Yip).
Type, if necessary, and select the function name in the Editor or R Console.    Then "Go to Declaration" or use shortcuts CTRL-B or Command-B.
Note: this is not useful for `.Primitive` (ie, internally implemented) functions.